# Live cycle image field flush with the side of the page

Tags: adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I am trying to get a livecycle image field to be right up against the side of the page that it is on. It seems that I always have a little space between the image and the edge of the page no matter what I do.

Here is an image so you can see the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs22z.jpg

The person should be on the edge of the page, he should be touching the bottom and right side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the image on a master page or just within the content pages/subforms?

If the image is in the content pages check that the 'content area' in the master page is the full width and height of the page (use the information in the layout tab).

For precise positioning choose anchor bottom right and use the x and y co-ordinates in the layout tab.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use the layout panel to check and set values for the content area width that contains your image field. Also set the width and positioning for the parent subform if you have the image in a subform.